# Spouse hiding money

Tags: theft, finance, divorce

Can a lawyer request payslips from an employer? I am separated and my spouse is hiding money in a separate account in an attempt to pay less maintenance.

Any advice? My location is South Africa.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you need to remove the theft tag. I would expect there is a law somewhere in which the government can request them, but I doubt you can as a person.